# How to make BATCH do a google search

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch program that will do a google search. Currently my code is thus:

```
@echo off
color 0a
:start
echo Please enter search terms
echo.
@echo off
set /p st="Keywords: "
start "" https://www.google.com/search?source="%st%"
```

However, this does not yield the result I am looking for. In stead, this url only brings up the google front page.

Comment: I bet if you Google searched for the answer to your question you would have found this: `https://www.google.com/search?q=SearchTerm`

Answer (score 0):

you can use let me google that for you it would be easier. google has a more complicated php than lmgtfy

```bat
@echo off
color 0a
:start
echo Please enter search terms
echo.
@echo off
set /p st="Keywords: "
start "" http://l m g t f y.com/?q="%st%"
```

Comment: you will need to replace space with +

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. I've found something that works fairly well called Duck Duck goose. My code is now:

```
@echo off
color 0a
cls
:start
set st="var"
echo Please enter search terms
echo.
@echo off
set /p st="Keywords: "
start "" https://duckduckgo.com/?q="%st%"&t=hg&ia=web
cls
```

So now I have https://www.google.com/search?q="SearchTerm" I have another question. Can I somehow make BATCH automatically change the spaces in my input to pluses?

EDIT: I changed my code to

```
@echo off
color 0a
cls
:start
set st="var"
echo Please enter search terms
echo.
@echo off
set /p st="Keywords: "
start "" https://www.google.com/search?q="%st%"
cls
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this:

```
@echo off
```

`enter https://www.google.com/search?q=an+example&sxsrf=ALeKk00Xjc7jT3Lnzlo2mWTgswvDTb4DmQ%3A1621012024123&source=hp&ei=OK6eYLKTBde7lwTm_57QCg&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYJ68SCwUchkdxZE6C7XwOjCnhbapBSXl&oq=an+example&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgQIIxAnOgsIABCxAxDHARCjAjoICAAQsQMQgwE6BQgAELEDOgQIABBDOgQILhBDOgIILjoECAAQDVD_CFjCIWDvI2gBcAB4AIABhAOIAfsOkgEHNS4xLjQuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiyj_2u1MnwAhXX3YUKHea_B6oQ4dUDCAc&uact=5`